# How to return a filtered map in jsx?

Tags: reactjs

I want to filter an array of objects and then map over them all and return the JSX but I can't get the syntax right.

```
...
  const filterFiles = (): ReactElement => {
    const filtered = cleanFiles?.filter(file => file.key === params.key);
      return(  
        filtered?.map(
            (file, index) =>
                <div key={index}>
                  <FileView data={file} layout={view} />
                </div>
          );
      );
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>{filterFiles()}</div>
    </>
  );
};
export { FileBrowser };
```

Ive also tried

```
  const filterFiles = (): ReactElement => {
    const filtered = cleanFiles?.filter(file => file.key === params.key);
      return(  
        <>
        filtered?.map((file, index) =>
                <div key={index}>
                  <FileView data={file} layout={view} />
                </div>
          );
          </>
      );
  };
```

[image]

Comment: What's not working? Your code seems mostly valid (though the return type for `filterFiles` should probably be an array, and account for the possible `undefined` results of your optional chaining)

Comment: I've added a screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your second approach (which will return a single React element, as your types suggest) is that you are missing the `{}` around the code inside the fragment `<></>`

```
const filterFiles = (): ReactElement => {
  const filtered = cleanFiles?.filter(file => file.key === params.key);
  return <>
    {filtered?.map((file, index) =>
      <div key={index}>
        <FileView data={file} layout={view} />
      </div>
    )}
  </>
};
```

I would use the above option, but for the sake of completeness:

The issue with your first option, was probably that you are saying the function returns a `ReactElement`, but it was in fact returning: `Array<ReactElement> | undefined` due to the `map()` returning an array, and the optional chaining (`?.`) returning undefined if the property didn't exist.